# How do I simulate the default Bucket for local app engine launcher on localhost?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yii

On GAE cloud platform I can use it through

```
file_put_contents('gs://#default#/hello.txt', 'Hello');
```

or return the bucket name with

```
CloudStorageTools::getDefaultGoogleStorageBucketName()
```

How do I simulate the cloud storage bucket in my localhost app launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The development server will automatically simulate cloud storage using the local file system. Buckets don't need to be created first as this is done automatically the first time you write to them. The only difference is that on the local development server CloudStorageTools::getDefaultGoogleStorageBucketName() will return the string 'app_default_bucket' while in production the default bucket name is usually 'your-app-id.appspot.com', but for practical purposes this makes no difference.

The following code will work the same way on both dev and prod:

```
// Get default bucket name
$defaultBucket = CloudStorageTools::getDefaultGoogleStorageBucketName();

// Write something to the default bucket
file_put_contents('gs://' . $defaultBucket . '/some_file.txt', 'Hello World');

// Read something back from the file
echo file_get_contents('gs://' . $defaultBucket . '/some_file.txt');
```

Comment: on prod I tried this but I think $defaultBucket returns nothing. Is it because google provide default storage with every app engine account?

Comment: This is a good question! In production the default bucket doesn't get created automatically. To set it up you still need to go to the old console at https://appengine.google.com -> <project_id> -> Administration -> Application Settings -> Cloud Integration (bottom of page).

Comment: What is the purpose of that default bucket, 'app_default_bucket'? If I need to put some data there before starting my app locally, how would I do that?